# Flutter: The method 'add' was called on null

Tags: list, flutter, dart

So I have created a simple notification class as follows:

```
class NamedNotification{
  String title;
  DateTime scheduledDate;
  int id;
  String description;

  NamedNotification(this.scheduledDate, this.id, this.title, this.description);
}
```

I use this class to keep track of my notifications and add them to a list whenever a new notification is created. I do this like this:

```
List<NamedNotification> notifications;

onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
        NotificationPlugin newNotification = NotificationPlugin(); 
        newNotification.showAtDayAndTimeNotification(_dateTime, id, title, description);
        NamedNotification listNotification = NamedNotification(_dateTime, id, title, description);
        print(listNotification);
        notifications.add(listNotification);
        id++;
    });
    print(id);
    Navigator.pop(context);
},
```

However, whenever I try to add my namedNotification to the list, I get this error:

```
The method 'add' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: add(Instance of 'NamedNotification')
```

I was wondering what the best way was to fix this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You forgot to init `notifications` 
Please init `notifications` like this

```
List<NamedNotification> notifications = [];
```

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem. I am curious, why was this causing an error?

Comment: add is a method belong to List. if you do not init variable when you call it , it will produce error and when you will see The method 'abc' was called on null. always check Instance

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.

Comment: Man I was starting to feel lost. +1